# How to create a custom view of a SharePoint list item for printing

Tags: list, sharepoint, printing

I have been searching the internet all day for something I think is pretty simple. I found one solution [here](http://planetparker.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=55) that would work for me but there are a couple of problems.

It seems that solution only works for items that were created in the list before the CEWP was added. Otherwise it will just show the form but none of the data that was entered for a new item. I think this has to do with the calculated field but I am honestly too new to SharePoint to know for sure.

The other thing that is not ideal with this solution is, it still prints the header of the site. My internet explorer is also printing only on the first page and the second page is blank. Works fine in chrome so that isn't a big deal at the moment, as it could be something with my computer itself causing that.

I have seen many people looking for a solution online to print the form and the current list item data but always hit a dead end. I would love for there to be a print button in the ribbon but at this point I would totally settle for just a blank page with the form populated with the list data from a single item on my list. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am at the end of my rope with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to write a special CSS file for PRINT alone where you will be hiding all the unwanted ELEMENTS.

```
<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="print" HREF="foo.css">
```

Inside this foo.css, you can write classes to hide required stuff. Like below you can hide the RIBBON by saying

```
#RibbonContainer
{
display:none;
}
```

Left Navigation :

```
#s4-leftpanel
{
display:none;
}
```